# Kendo ASP.NET MVC Grid Pageable() attributes combination

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, kendo-ui

Check the two `Pageable()` lines of code below, how do I combine them in a single instruction?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid")  
    ...         
    .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 50, 100 }).Info(true)) // 1st
    .Pageable(p => p.AlwaysVisible(false))                                // 2nd
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
       .Ajax()
       .PageSize(15)
       ...
   )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid")  
    ...         
    .Pageable(p => p.AlwaysVisible(false).PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 50, 100 }).Info(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
       .Ajax()
       .PageSize(15)
       ...
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with code brackets.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
.Name("Grid")  
...         
.Pageable(p => {
     p.AlwaysVisible(false);
     P.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 50, 100 }).Info(true);
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
   .Ajax()
   .PageSize(15)
   ...
```

)
)